# how to implement 'daisychaining' of pluggable function in python?

Tags: python

here is the problem:

1) suppose that I have some measure data (like 1Msample read from my electronics) and I need to process them by a processing chain.

2) this processing chain consists of different operations, which can be swapped/omitted/have different parameters. A typical example would be to take this data, first pass them via a lookup table, then do exponential fit, then multiply by some calibration factors

3) now, as I do not know what algorithm the the best, I'd like to evaluate at each stage best possible implementation (as an example, the LUTs can be produced by 5 ways and I want to see which one is the best)

4) i'd like to daisychain those functions such, that I would construct a 'class' containing top-level algorithm and owning (i.e. pointing) to child class, containing lower-level algorithm.

I was thinking to use double-linked-list and generate sequence like:

myCaptureClass.addDataTreatment(pmCalibrationFactor(opt, pmExponentialFit (opt, pmLUT (opt))))

where myCaptureClass is the class responsible for datataking and it should as well (after the data being taken) trigger the top-level data processing module (pm). This processing would first go deep into the bottom-child (lut), treat data there, then middle (expofit), then top (califactors) and return the data to the capture, which would return the data to the requestor.

Now this has several issues:

1) everywhere on the net is said that in python one should not use double-linked-lists
2) this seems to me highly inefficient because the data vectors are huge, hence i would prefer solution using generator function, but i'm not sure how to provide the 'plugin-like' mechanism.

could someone give me a hint how to solve this using 'plugin-style' and generator so I do not need to process vector of X megabytes of data and process them 'on-request' as is correct when using generator function?

thanks a lot

david

An addendum to the problem:

it seems that I did not express myself exactly. Hence: the data are generated by an external HW card plugged into VME crate. They are 'fetched' in a single block transfer to the python tuple, which is stored in myCaptureClass.

The set of operation to be applied is in fact on a stream data, represented by this tuple. Even exponential fit is stream operation (it is a set of variable state filters applied on each sample).

The parameter 'opt' i've mistakenly shown was to express, that each of those data processing classes has some configuration data which come with, and modify behaviour of the method used to operate on data.

The goal is to introduce into myCaptureClass a daisychained class (rather than function), which - when user asks for data - us used to process 'raw' data into final form.

In order to 'save' memory resources i thought it might be a good idea to use generator function to provide the data.

from this perspective it seems that the closest match to what i want to do is shown in code of bukzor. I'd prefer to have a class implementation instead of function, but i guess this is just a cosmetic stuff of implementing **call** operator in particular class, which realizes the data operation....

Comment: If you could give us a simple example of input / output, we can give concrete answers.

Comment: You should use a python list where you would want a doubly-linked-list in C++.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I imagine you would do this. I expect this is incomplete, since I don't fully understand your problem statement. Please let me know what I've done wrong :)

```
class ProcessingPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, *functions, **kwargs):
        self.functions = functions
        self.data = kwargs.get('data')
    def __call__(self, data):
        return ProcessingPipeline(*self.functions, data=data)
    def __iter__(self):
        data = self.data
        for func in self.functions:
            data = func(data)
        return data

# a few (very simple) operators, of different kinds
class Multiplier(object):
    def __init__(self, by):
        self.by = by
    def __call__(self, data):
        for x in data:
            yield x * self.by

def add(data, y):
    for x in data:
        yield x + y

from functools import partial
by2 = Multiplier(by=2)
sub1 = partial(add, y=-1)
square = lambda data: ( x*x for x in data )

pp = ProcessingPipeline(square, sub1, by2)

print list(pp(range(10)))
print list(pp(range(-3, 4)))
```

Output:

```
$ python how-to-implement-daisychaining-of-pluggable-function-in-python.py 
[-2, 0, 6, 16, 30, 48, 70, 96, 126, 160]
[16, 6, 0, -2, 0, 6, 16]
```

Comment: I've tried to modify function by2 to use class.  I have created class, overriding `__call__` function using argument data. The `y=2` was passed to constructor. `__call__` uses `yield` as the mul function.
I though that you: create a partial function,construct data-empty processing pipeline, which is then called and returns same class, but with data attached to it. And that final `list(pp(..))` command invokes `__iter__`  calling each function. If function is a class, it should call its `__call__`. BUt something is wrong because it surprisingly expects my class to be iterable. What is wrong?

Comment: @DavidBelohrad: Please use [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or the [pocoo pastein](http://paste.pocoo.org/). That will help preserve the content for other readers, and it makes it easy for me to reply.

Comment: @DavidBelohrad: Your code is a bit more complex than it needs to be. Also your use of partial is incorrect. You should think of partial as reseting the default values of a function. By doing `partial(Constructor, y=2)`, you're changing the default y to be 2, but you haven't constructed an object. What you *really* want is just the constructor. Fixed (untested) code: https://gist.github.com/2466345

Comment: I see, so at the end I do not need any partial at all if my processing chain is composed only of classes with known values at the time of construction.

Thanks a lot for englighting me.... (if I could vote, you'd definitely get it :) Next time i'll use gist as well.

Comment: @DavidBelohrad: Yep, you got it. You can accept an answer ;) You could say that `partial` is used to add a bit of state to a function, which isn't necessary for an object; they naturally have state in their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `functional` module from pypi. It has a compose function to compose two callables. With that, you can chain functions together.

Both that module, and `functool` provide a `partial` function, for partial-application.

You can use the composed functions in a generator expression just like any other.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly what you want, I feel like I should point out that you can put whatever you want inside a list comprehension:

```
l = [myCaptureClass.addDataTreatment(
          pmCalibrationFactor(opt, pmExponentialFit (opt, pmLUT (opt))))
     for opt in data]
```

will create a new list of data that has been passed through the composed functions.

Or you could create a generator expression for looping over, this won't construct a whole new list, it will just create an iterator. I don't think that there's any advantage to doing things this way as opposed to just processing the data in the body of the loop, but it's kind of interesting to look at:

```
d = (myCaptureClass.addDataTreatment(
          pmCalibrationFactor(opt, pmExponentialFit (opt, pmLUT (opt))))
     for opt in data)
for thing in d:
    # do something
    pass
```

Or is `opt` the data?

Comment: Note that this is a list comprehension, not a generator, but of course the syntax is almost identical.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Your code already generates a list. To pass it to the list constructor would give a second (value-identical) list.

Comment: Right, sorry, I was just saying that putting the expression inside the list constructor function makes it a generator expression, and putting it inside a list literal makes it a list comprehension.

Comment: Right, but you can also just put it in brackets, and the result is a generator object.

Comment: If by brackets you mean parens, then yes, and actually that would be more efficient, certainly in terms of memory.